# css Nth. all siblings after this one

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to have it so that all siblings after the image tab.. are selected. So i can put them besides the images as shown in the image.
cannot seem to find the right one for this. Can anyone give me some help?`

```
<section class="homeOver">
        <article>
        <h2>OVER CUISINE</h2>
        <p>Cuisine geeft al kookboeken uit sinds 1977. In de webwinkel zijn kookboeken te vinden in alle categorieën en uit alle delen van de wereld, in verschillende talen.</p><br/>
        <img src="images/About/about.jpg" alt="over ons image">
        <p>Boeken die niet in de winkel op voorraad zijn kunnen, mits leverbaar, overal ter wereld worden besteld. Er worden rechtstreeks boeken geïmporteerd uit landen als Egypte, Iran en India. Wekelijks komen, behalve uit Nederland, nieuwe boeken binnen uit Engeland, Amerika en Frankrijk.</p>

            <p>Cuisine bied alles om uw kookervaring zo prettig mogelijk te maken.</p>
            
            <p>Eet smakelijk!</p>
            
             <em>Het Cuisine Team.</em></p>

             <button></button>
            </article>
    </section>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRGmU.png)`

This is what i am aiming for.

I am expecting the thing to end up in the image. all siblins before the image should have it's normal path. But all after the imag tag should be set in a grid.. I just dont know how to select that in CSs.

Comment: The selector would be `img ~ *` but that won't help with your styling.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just go old school and use float:left?

```css
img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

button {
  all: unset;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  background-color: #D98A3F;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: coral;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

h2,
em {
  color: #418C9F;
}

em {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<section class="homeOver">
  <article>
    <h2>OVER CUISINE</h2>
    <p>Cuisine geeft al kookboeken uit sinds 1977. In de webwinkel zijn kookboeken te vinden in alle categorieën en uit alle delen van de wereld, in verschillende talen.</p><br />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/30/300/400" alt="over ons image">
    <p>Boeken die niet in de winkel op voorraad zijn kunnen, mits leverbaar, overal ter wereld worden besteld. Er worden rechtstreeks boeken geïmporteerd uit landen als Egypte, Iran en India. Wekelijks komen, behalve uit Nederland, nieuwe boeken binnen uit
      Engeland, Amerika en Frankrijk.</p>

    <p>Cuisine bied alles om uw kookervaring zo prettig mogelijk te maken.</p>

    <p>Eet smakelijk!</p>

    <em>Het Cuisine Team.</em></p>
    <button>LEES VERDER OVER CUISINE</button>

  </article>
</section>
```

**Edited** added grid solution below:

```css
img {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

button {
  all: unset;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #d98a3f;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: fit-content(0) 1fr;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

h2,
em {
  color: #418c9f;
}

em {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<section class="homeOver">
  <article>
    <h2>OVER CUISINE</h2>
    <p>Cuisine geeft al kookboeken uit sinds 1977. In de webwinkel zijn kookboeken te vinden in alle categorieën en uit alle delen van de wereld, in verschillende talen.</p><br />
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='image'>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/30/300/400" alt="over ons image">
      </div>
      <div class='text'>
        <p>Boeken die niet in de winkel op voorraad zijn kunnen, mits leverbaar, overal ter wereld worden besteld. Er worden rechtstreeks boeken geïmporteerd uit landen als Egypte, Iran en India. Wekelijks komen, behalve uit Nederland, nieuwe boeken binnen
          uit Engeland, Amerika en Frankrijk.</p>

        <p>Cuisine bied alles om uw kookervaring zo prettig mogelijk te maken.</p>

        <p>Eet smakelijk!</p>

        <em>Het Cuisine Team.</em></p>
        <button>LEES VERDER OVER CUISINE</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Finally here's the "brute force" grid approach that doesn't change any html markup. This is very much **not recommended** as it'll break very easily but shows how you can use child and sibling combinators and grid to get the effect you're looking for. You'd never put this in to production but here you go....

```css
article {
  display: grid;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr;
}

article>*:nth-child(-n + 2) {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}

img {
  grid-column: 1;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  grid-row: 3 / span 8;
}

button {
  all: unset;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #d98a3f;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img~* {
  grid-column: 2;
}

h2,
em {
  color: #418c9f;
}

em {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<section class="homeOver">
  <article>
    <h2>OVER CUISINE</h2>
    <p>Cuisine geeft al kookboeken uit sinds 1977. In de webwinkel zijn kookboeken te vinden in alle categorieën en uit alle delen van de wereld, in verschillende talen.</p><br />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/30/300/400" alt="over ons image">
    <p>Boeken die niet in de winkel op voorraad zijn kunnen, mits leverbaar, overal ter wereld worden besteld. Er worden rechtstreeks boeken geïmporteerd uit landen als Egypte, Iran en India. Wekelijks komen, behalve uit Nederland, nieuwe boeken binnen uit
      Engeland, Amerika en Frankrijk.</p>
    <p>Cuisine bied alles om uw kookervaring zo prettig mogelijk te maken.</p>
    <p>Eet smakelijk!</p>
    <em>Het Cuisine Team.</em></p>
    <button>LEES VERDER OVER CUISINE</button>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Hey Adam, 
I could but we are encouraged not to use float. 
Teach has a problem with it so i am trying to avoid oldschool techniques. 
Thats why i was thinking of putting it in a grid.